# android - create a virtual camera or overwrite the real cam stream? (/dev/msm_camera/frame0, v4l2loopback)?

Tags: android, camera

I'm currently working on a project about latencies in image and video transmission.

Do I have the ability (assuming root) to create a virtual camera or overwrite the real cam framebuffer with the same picture or raw video stream?
I want to use this cam in skype for example.

I through about something like v4l2loopback to manipulate the picture...
i tested things like that, but this dosn´t work...

```
ln -s /sdcard/image.jpg /dev/msm_camera/msm_camera0
dd if=/dev/graphics/fb0 of=/dev/msm_camera/frame0
cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > /dev/msm_camera/frame0
```

Is this possible?
I´am using a HTC Desire HD with ICS

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I'll start by saying i can only give you a leading start.
You can use introspy to investigate how the operation system is using the camera. 
Than you can exploit it, and make a hook, possibly replacing the original stream.

Link to introspy:

https://github.com/iSECPartners/Introspy-Android/blob/master/README.md